# Android: How to capture the end of panning on MapView

Tags: android

Could you please tell me how to capture the end of panning of MapView? At the beginning, I thought I could use the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP. However, when my touch is moved fast, the panning animation is still in progress while the ACTION_UP event is already fired before.

Comment: did you you want  to handle zoom events please confirm?

Comment: No, I did not. I want to know when the panning is finished.

Comment: could you please elaborate since I didn't get what is the exact problem.

Comment: Did you work out how to do this as I am stuck on exactly the same thing. I want to know where the mapview finally stops so I can get the coordinates!

Answer (score 0):

I had to come up with a solution to this problem also.  It appears there is not a method in the android SDK to handle this event.  What I did was create a timer that runs every 200ms and checks to see if the centerpoint of the mapview has changed.  If it has and the a flag is set.  The timer method knows when the panning has stopped when the centerpoint is no longer changing(oldMapCenter==newMapCenter).  It may not be the best solution, but it is working for me. Insert the code below in your MapActivity.

NOTE:  This will not update the view WHILE the user is panning, only AFTER.

```
    GeoPoint newMapCenter,oldMapCenter;
    int newZoomLevel=0,oldZoomLevel=0;
    Boolean isMoving=false;
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

         autoUpdate = new Timer();
          autoUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
            ((Activity) getActivity()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {

                 if(oldMapCenter==null){
                     oldMapCenter=mapView.getMapCenter();
                 }else{
                 newMapCenter=mapView.getMapCenter();
                 if(!geoPointsAreSame(newMapCenter,oldMapCenter)&&    (!isMoving)){
                     isMoving=true;
                 }else{
                     if(geoPointsAreSame(newMapCenter,oldMapCenter)&&(isMoving)){
                          //Insert update overlay code here
                         isMoving=false;
                     }
                 }
                 oldMapCenter=newMapCenter;
                 }
                 newZoomLevel=mapView.getZoomLevel();

                 if(oldZoomLevel==0){
                     oldZoomLevel=mapView.getZoomLevel();
                 }else{
                     if(oldZoomLevel!=newZoomLevel){
                            //insert update overlay code here

                 }
             }
             oldZoomLevel=mapView.getZoomLevel();


         }
             }


            private boolean geoPointsAreSame(GeoPoint newMapCenter,
                    GeoPoint oldMapCenter) {
                if(newMapCenter.getLatitudeE6()==oldMapCenter.getLatitudeE6()){
                    if(newMapCenter.getLongitudeE6()==oldMapCenter.getLongitudeE6()){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
                }

            });
           }
          }, 3000, 200); // updates each 200 millisecs`-
```